# Mongodb won't start/restart due to corrupted mongod.conf file

Tags: mongodb

Read & write access is enabled for the mongodb instance. This is a huge security risk. Here's what it looks like:

```
[root@ip-XXX-AA-BB-YYY ~]# mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.4.5
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("a81d8b04-5edf-4a34-9b68-8c3bce8b5849") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.5
---
The server generated these startup warnings when booting: 
        2021-04-18T05:55:37.285+00:00: Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted
        2021-04-18T05:55:37.285+00:00: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended
        2021-04-18T05:55:37.285+00:00: Soft rlimits too low
        2021-04-18T05:55:37.285+00:00:         currentValue: 1024
        2021-04-18T05:55:37.285+00:00:         recommendedMinimum: 64000
---
---
        Enable MongoDB's free cloud-based monitoring service, which will then receive and display
        metrics about your deployment (disk utilization, CPU, operation statistics, etc).

        The monitoring data will be available on a MongoDB website with a unique URL accessible to you
        and anyone you share the URL with. MongoDB may use this information to make product
        improvements and to suggest MongoDB products and deployment options to you.

        To enable free monitoring, run the following command: db.enableFreeMonitoring()
        To permanently disable this reminder, run the following command: db.disableFreeMonitoring()
---
> 
>
```

I'm unable to start/restart mongodb. My developer says it's due to the corrupted `mongod.conf` here. Here's the content:

```
# mongod.conf
  
# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true
# engine:
# wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0

#security:
# authorization: enabled
#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Due to security reasons of bindIp being 0.0.0.0, I have shut down the server altogether. How can I fix this problem?

```
[root@ip-XXX-AA-BB-YYY ~]# sudo service mongod start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start mongod.service
Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@ip-XXX-AA-BB-YYY ~]# sudo systemctl status mongod
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: **failed** (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-04-18 11:24:00 UTC; 41s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 3613 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS **(code=exited, status=14)**
  Process: 3610 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3607 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3606 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Apr 18 11:23:59 ip-XXX-AA-BB-YYY.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting MongoDB Database Server...
Apr 18 11:23:59 ip-XXX-AA-BB-YYY.us-east-2.compute.internal mongod[3613]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
Apr 18 11:23:59 ip-XXX-AA-BB-YYY.us-east-2.compute.internal mongod[3613]: forked process: 3617
Apr 18 11:24:00 ip-XXX-AA-BB-YYY.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=14
Apr 18 11:24:00 ip-XXX-AA-BB-YYY.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: **Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.**
Apr 18 11:24:00 ip-XXX-AA-BB-YYY.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Apr 18 11:24:00 ip-XXX-AA-BB-YYY.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
[root@ip-XXX-AA-BB-YYY ~]# 
[root@ip-XXX-AA-BB-YYY ~]# mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.4.5
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
[root@ip-XXX-AA-BB-YYY ~]#
```

I couldn't stop mongo either and so I have rebooted the AWS instance which shut down the mongodb. Now, I can't start or restart the mongo.

Here's the log file from `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-18T11:23:59.814+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"main","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-18T11:23:59.817+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-18T11:23:59.825+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-18T11:23:59.826+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-18T11:23:59.826+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":3617,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongo","architecture":"64-bit","host":"ip-XXX-AA-BB-YYY.us-east-2.compute.internal"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-18T11:23:59.826+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.5","gitVersion":"ff5cb77101b052fa02da43b8538093486cf9b3f7","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"amazon2","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-18T11:23:59.826+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo)","version":"Kernel 4.14.203-156.332.amzn2.x86_64"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-18T11:23:59.826+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1","port":27017},"processManagement":{"fork":true,"pidFilePath":"/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid","timeZoneInfo":"/usr/share/zoneinfo"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongo","journal":{"enabled":true}},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-18T11:23:59.827+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/var/lib/mongo","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-18T11:23:59.827+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=256M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-18T11:24:00.504+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":13,"message":"[1618745040:504678][3617:0x7f4abfab2280], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 808: /var/lib/mongo/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-18T11:24:00.504+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":13,"message":"[1618745040:504970][3617:0x7f4abfab2280], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 808: /var/lib/mongo/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-18T11:24:00.505+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":13,"message":"[1618745040:505157][3617:0x7f4abfab2280], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 808: /var/lib/mongo/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-18T11:24:00.505+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22347,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version. This may be due to an unsupported upgrade or downgrade."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-18T11:24:00.505+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":28595,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Terminating.","attr":{"reason":"13: Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-18T11:24:00.505+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":28595,"file":"src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp","line":947}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-18T11:24:00.505+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

Comment: A "corrupted" config file (this is a plain simple text file) seems to be very unlikely.

Comment: Check the log file `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`. Enable `security.authorization`, see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Okay thanks. Any idea what could be the reason for the error in starting the mongodb then? Also, I'm not sure what to take sense of the log. Can I upload it somewhere?

Comment: ""reason":"13: Permission denied" - check the permissions.